# How do I read the "Recent Activity" page?

Tags: support, notifications, recent-activity

I was looking at my profile the other day, and I realized that I have no idea what most of the symbols on the *Recent Activity* page mean.  Can someone explain them to me?

[image: Recent Activity (Censored)]

What I'm having trouble understanding, for the most part, are those boxes next to the notifications.  Can someone please explain to me what they mean?  Do they only pertain to my personal activity, or also to the activity of others on my topics?

---

I've provided a screenshot of my recent activity page for this week, & I'd appreciate it if the values in this image were used as examples.  This is the most varied page I could come up with at the moment, & I'm aware that I'm missing some types of notifications.  If those could also be explained I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use top half of the page to decide to select a report and a timeframe to view changes.

Here's how to read  the reports:

**Reputation reports**

- Left column: timestamp
- Green boxes: reason of rep gain (usually, number of upvotes) and reputation generated
- Red boxes: reason of rep loss (number of downvotes) and reputation lost
- Right column: question or answer that has changed

**Other reports**

- Left column: timestamp
- Center column: user who made the change
- Right column: summary of change

Comment: For the reputation report there's also: reputation gained from bounties, reputation gained from accepts and reputation lost from flags.

Comment: Ah, so the top number is the number of votes, and the lower one is the reputation result?  Thank you very much!  What does [acc 2] mean though, and why is that text yellow instead of white?

Comment: It means acc-epted. It's a different colour to catch your attention :) (You can also have "bty" there; that's for bounty-related rep changes.)

Comment: So 'acc' is questions of my own that I have accepted an answer to.  Does it display differently if someone accepts MY answer on a question?

Comment: @Gnome `acc` is used in both cases. The distinguishing factor is whether it's 2 reputation (you accepted it) or 15 reputation (you got accepted).